# Where are the settings for Adium located

Tags: macos, migration, adium

I am moving computers and want to copy the Adium settings over.
What is the path to all the settings for Adium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably find everyting you want right from the [Adium Documentation](http://adium.im/help/pgs/Miscellaneous-LocationsAdiumFiles.html):

> Adium places the majority of its preferences here:
>
> - *Home Folder → Library → Application Support → Adium 2.0*
>
> There is also a preference file at:
>
> - *Home Folder → Library → Preferences → com.adiumX.adiumX.plist*
>
> Message transcripts can be found in this directory:
>
> - *Home Folder → Library → Application Support → Adium 2.0 → Users → Default → Logs*
>
> The Adium Xtras you have installed are stored in subfolder of the "Adium 2.0" folder mentioned above:
>
> - *Home Folder → Library → Application Support → Adium 2.0*